# What variable type should I use to store types of a non sealed class or interface?

Tags: c#, class, types, interface

### README

- I have thousands of creatures, and each creature derives from
  **Creature**.
- An example of a creature is **Creature_MoonDancer**.
- **Creature** is a class that can only be instantiated if a **CreatureData** object is passed into its constructor.
- I want to find a way to scope any sealed type that inherits from
  **Creature** to one **CreatureData** in a **Dictionary**.
- Each creature may only be linked up to a maximum of 1 instance of
  **CreatureData** in creatureDatabaseDictionary.

---

Here is **CreatureData**, a class with information that needs to be fed into **Creature**'s constructor to instantiate it:

```
--CreatureData.cs

using UnityEngine.UI;

[System.Serializable]
class CreatureData {
    //To be set by Unity engine's inspector.
    [SerializeField] private Sprite creatureHead;
    [SerializeField] private int creatureStartingDamage;
    Sprite CreatureHead {
        get{
            return creatureHead;
        }
    }
    Sprite CreatureStartingDamage {
        get{
            return creatureStartingDamage;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here I have an abstract class **Creature** which encompasses what a creature is.

```
--Creature.cs

public class Creature {
    protected Sprite creatureHead;
    protected int creatureDamage;
    public Creature(CreatureData creatureData){
        creatureHead = creatureData.CreatureHead;
        creatureDamage = creatureData.CreatureStartingDamage
    }
    public abstract void getAttackedBy(Creature other);
}
```

---

There are thousands of sealed creature types that derive from **Creature** and here is one example:

```
--Creature_MoonDancer.cs

public sealed class Creature_MoonDancer : Creature{
    private int moonOrbsInPossession;
    public Creature_MoonDancer (CreatureData creatureData, int startingMoonOrbs) : base(creatureData){
        moonOrbsInPossession = startingMoonOrbs;
    }
    public override void getAttackedBy(Creature other){
        if(moonOrbsInPossession > other.creatureDamage){
            Debug.Log("MoondancerWins");
        }
        else if(Random.value < 0.5)
            Debug.Log("MoondancerDies");
        else
            Debug.Log("MoondancerWins");
    }
}
```

---

CreatureDatabase will contain a **Dictionary** that stores **CreatureData** and links any sealed class that derives from **Creature** to up to 1 corresponding **CreatureData** as such:

```
--CreatureDatabase.cs

public class CreatureDatabase : MonoBehaviour {
    private static class CreatureDataCustomSerializableDictionary
        : CustomSerializableDictionary<typeof(Creature),CreatureData> {}
    //TODO: Create custom property drawer for CustomSerializableDictionary
    [SerializeField] private CreatureDataCustomSerializableDictionary creatureDatabaseDictionary;

    public CreatureDatabaseDictionary {
        get{
            return creatureDatabaseDictionary;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is the game manager trying to get values out from the creatureDatabaseDictionary **Dictionary**:

```
--GameManager.cs

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour{
    [SerializeField] private CreatureDatabase creatureDatabase;
    private Creature SummonMoonDancer(){
        CreatureData creatureData;
        bool success = creatureDatabase.CreatureDatabaseDictionary.TryGetValue(typeof(Creature_MoonDancer), out creatureData);
        if(success == false){
            Debug.LogError("Tried summoning MoonDancer when creature database did not have a typeof(MoonDancer) key");
        }
        else{
            return new Creature_MoonDancer(creatureData), Player.GetInt("NumberOfMoonorbsInPlayersPouch");
        }

    }
}
```

---

Here are some of the project requirements:

- The game balancing team are required to balance the game without
  modifying code.
- **Important**: The game balancing team must not be able to insert any keyvaluepairs with
  keys that are not creature types.

Comment: Why `typeof(mybaby)` and not just `mybaby`? It's not `typeof(string) message = "hello";`

Comment: I don't want to store an instance of an object which has mybaby as it's base in mychild. I just want to store the type of an non-sealed class or interface with mybaby as it's base into mychild.

Comment: can't create an instance of an abstract class anyway

one way would be to create an IBaby interface that all mybaby children implement

Comment: Then you need a `Type` variable. You can't constrain the possible values to subclasses of a particular type, unless you wrap it in a property and perform runtime checks.

Comment: If you want to store a type then you use the `Type` type.  The `typeof` operator returns a `Type` object, which you can then assign to a variable of the `Type` type.

Comment: @Muckeypuck So C# doesn't support this? Gosh... ... terrible D;

Comment: not when it had the abstract modifier anyways :)

Comment: You also can't declare a variable of type "integer from 1 to 20", or "string with no special characters". You can make these types yourself and have them enforce their constraints at runtime, though.

Comment: @Blorgbeard But I can doenum MyEnum :

Comment: Oops I can't edit the previous comment so ignore it.

You mean like "random integer that is divisible by <value>" or "random string with no <certain character>"? They can only be done runtime, as they have to pass through a function with a parameter that is not known at compile time

However, there is no such thing as a "random class", and also, "derives from <typeof(class)>" is a function with input parameters known at compile time.

Comment: Integers and strings can contain any arbitary value, but classes have their base class and interfaces known at compile time, so I don't see their similarity in this context.

Comment: It really sounds like you need to create a series of XML/JSON (or something) files that will give the data for each creature and then perform some sort of validation on the files to ensure that they don't contain any invalid key-value pairs.

Comment: @RyanAWE - And no-one can give you any rep. You need to earn it by asking and answering questions.

Comment: @Enigmativity  I don't want to store the paths of where my png files are located as strings in .json or .xml files, as it will heavily limit the flexibility of my project, meaning renaming files and/or transferring them in between folders will be a severe pain.

Comment: Classes' base classes and interfaces are known at compile-time, but so what? The characters in strings which are defined at compile-time are also known at compile-time. You want a variable, which is assignable at runtime. There needs to be a runtime check.

Comment: @RyanAWE - You've made this requirement very confusing from the start and then when you've got some more concrete information you've said no to the most basic thing that you most probably need. If the balancing team can't modify the source then they must modify something else - XML, JSON, DB, etc - but you've said no to this. It's either hard-coded in the code or it's external. I really can't think of any other way. I think you need to think thru your requirements again.

Comment: @Enigmativity The data input destination for the game balancing team will be through editing the values from the GameDatabase component using a custom property drawer in Unity's inspector. Is this specific enough?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I still can't find a way to write a wrapper class to do this. I do not want to use enumerations in this, because I do not want to add any value into the enum type whenever I create a new class.

Comment: I am not familiar with how Unity works, so I don't know what kind of wiring up you need to do to get it to work with a custom property drawer. As far as the C# goes, does a simple class with a single readonly public field of type `Type` and a ctor which checks that the `Type` passed to it meets requirements work?

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code written so that it compiles with an example assignment:

```
public interface mybaby {}
public class mytom : mybaby {}
public class mydick : mybaby {}
public class myharry : mybaby {}

public class Test
{
    mybaby mychild = new myharry();
}
```

This is working, valid, C# code.

Comment: The OP has asked - (1) What if `myharry` has many data members and wastes a lot of memory? (2) I want to reserve the freedom of making `myharry` an abstract class.

Comment: I don't see what having many data members impacts this. I don't see why it wastes lots of memory. Are you thinking that by assigning `myharry` to `mybaby` that it somehow changes the type? It doesn't. It's still a `myharry` type, it's just assigned to a variable as a `mybaby` type.

Comment: Ultimately you need to create an instance of an object that can be assigned to `mybaby`. So if `myharry` is abstract the you'll have `public class mygrandchild : myharry { ...} ` that you would then use, like `mybaby mychild = new mygrandchild();`.

Comment: Regarding wastage of memory, I have no reason to use the instance of mychild in my code. All I need is the type.

Comment: For example, Dictionary<mybaby,myvalue>(), where I will never, in any situation, ever need to use any data member or method in the key of <mybaby,myvalue>. The memory allocated for the instance is wasted as it is never meant to be used.

Comment: What is the way to do it while avoiding using enums? Perhaps something like <typeof(mybaby),myvalue>?

Comment: @RyanAWE - Your comments are confusing me. I don't think you have described your problem very well. What is it that you're trying to do from a higher-level.

Comment: @RyanAWE - If you want the type of something then the declaration would be `Type mychildtype = typeof(myharry)`. Does that help?

Comment: Ok I will post what I am trying to do from a higher-level in a new answer.

Comment: @RyanAWE - Don't do it in a new answer. Just edit your quesiton.

Comment: Okay I have changed the question. Could I have some reputation please? I can't use the chat rooms... I think the reputation are meant to filter bots but as you can see I'm clearly not one. Thanks!

Comment: @RyanAWE - Reputation is meant to give people time to understand the rules. For example, like answering your own question rather than leaving comments or editing your question. ;-)